# Unable to Save edited IP config Network settings in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 .and my networking settings are Proxy oriented. I added IPv4 settings and saved them but when I see the added IPv4 settings again, the subnetmask settings are not saved as I entered. In the place of subnetmask (255.255.252.0) a default number 22 is saved as show in the image below.

[image]

I don't know why that number has been appearing again and again even after saving required IPv4 settings.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the IP address and gateway that you are trying to set - the problem may be that the mask is not compatible with other settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not error, `255.255.252.0/22` it's a representation.

Restart your network manager for network problem

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (open terminal) and type:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```